# What is the limit/maximum of Textattribute "Tracking"?

Tags: java, fonts

Sample code:

```
 public void paint( Graphics g ) {
                    super.paint( g );
                    Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
                    attributes.put( TextAttribute.TRACKING, 10 );
                    g.setFont( new Font( "Arial", 0, 10 ).deriveFont( attributes ) );

                    g.drawString( "bonus", 100, 100 );
                }
```

If I increase the value for Tracking > 10, then it will be ignored. What is the limit for Tracking? 
Apidocs only say values are *desireable* between -0.1 and 0.3, but what is the limit?

Why i want Tracking>10? The software renders our customer's PDFs with Java. The parser converts PDf's character spacing to TRACKING. While testing i faced some example PDFs where this extraordinary spacing is used (19!). In order to build a workaround for cases exceeding the limit I need the minimum/maximum for TRACKING-Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Tracking values are typically between -0.1 and 0.3; values outside
>   this range are generally not desireable.

also read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#TRACKING)

Comment: I read this, it does not mention a concrete limit. Why 10 works and 11 does not?

Comment: because its related to your Font point size, change your font point size to 11. it should work.

Comment: I already tried different fonts with different size - same result